# Word Document as body of email

Tags: gmail, microsoft-word-2010, windows-live-mail, document-management

I am using Word 2010 and I need to send a word document (with images) using either windows live mail or gmail but I need to have it appear as the body of the email NOT an attachment. Can anybody help? I found instructions that showed me how to access the quick access toolbar in word and add send to mail recipient command to the toolbar but when I do that it creates the button that shows an email symbol but it remains greyed out so I can't click it

[image: view of word toolbar]

Comment: Have you tried copying and pasting into the mail compose window?

Comment: @Eddie - unfortunately because the document contains a lot of detailed structure such as special fonts, borders, colors, images etc. when I try to copy and paste I loss the special effects and the images.

Comment: It was worth a shot. Only mostly unrelated: I _hate_ receiving email messages like that. What's wrong with plain text?

Answer (score 1):

> word document (...) appear as the body of the email NOT an attachment

That **cannot be done**, and shouldn't be attempted, because the capabilities of the respective recipients system usually do not include true rendering of word documents.

Remember, the recipient may "read" your email on a cellphone, a computer with a different operating system, a computer without "Word" installed, a computer with a *different version* of "Word" installed, a text-only terminal, a text-to-speech system, or even a braille line.

Nowadays, HTML and some markup are tolerated by some mail clients and displayed to *some* extent (this is frowned upon by many professionals, as it brings a multitude of new problems, like bloated emails, and the very possibility of inconsistencies between say, text and HTML versions)... so, anything else simply *has* to go into attachments.